# Adaptive rendering for Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, adaptive-design

MVC has a dll you can reference in your project called "system.web.webpages" and you use this to perform adaptive rendering inside your "application_start" method of the global.asax file like below:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
            {
                ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
                    ("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            });
```

**Is there a similar feature in Web Forms?**

If at all possible, I don't want to create a separate Mobile folder with a Mobile masterpage and check in the preinit event and switch over to render my mobile masterpage. It's obviously not as flexible for checking the specific type of mobile device, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice to detect a mobile device and adapt your rendering. Preferable with an uptodate mobile device list, you can use for example 51degrees.mobi for that.

[Here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application) is an extensive whitepaper to help you on your way.

Edit:

According to the whitepaper:
"This is easy to do. For example, you can add a PreInit handler such as the following to a Web Form:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
        MasterPageFile = "~/Mobile.Master";
}
```

"

If 51degrees.mobi provides you with the exact mobile device, you can set the masterpagefile for your different devices there.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for... However, for MVC, the browser can already render the view correctly based on the device type using the "DisplayModelProvider" I stated up above. With WebForms, if you want to know the device type (for the form to be able to render properly, you'll need to get the premium package, not the free one (which just tells you whether it's coming in on a mobile device or not). The free one is basically useless since you can already check the "Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice" property built into .Net.

Comment: According to the docs on mobi, you'll be able to tell exactly what kind of mobile device it is. Will it be able to properly render your WebForm pages (as in MVC, described in my original post) without redirecting to a specific MasterPage (with different CSS styles) for that device? With MVC, there's no need to redirect if you just include different masterpage files in your Views\Shared folder. For instance, with the above original post checking for an iPhone, if you have the following file in the specified folder (_Layout.iPhone.cshtml), your View will render properly without any changes.

Comment: Edited my answer with an example for WebForms